# iterm 2 ssh into multiple hosts at once

Tags: ssh, iterm2

I have multiple hostnames that are named like this

```
hostname-asd87
hostname-sdf09
hostname-yxv28
hostname-czv14
hostname-efv32
hostname-xav99
```

I want to ssh into them at once using a wildcard or something that looks like this

```
ssh hostname-*
```

Then I should get multiple panes for each session

[image]

How would this be possible?